# Can't use two ore more filters with Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, filter

I'm using Elasticsearch in my project.
My Elasticsearch query is like that:

```
Array(
    [index] => galaxy
    [type] => galaxy
    [size] => 1000
    [from] => 0
    [body] => Array(
        [query] => Array(
            [filtered] => Array(
                [query] => Array(
                    [query_string] => Array(
                        [default_operator] => AND
                        [query] => vestel*
                    )
                )
                [filter] => Array(
                    [bool] => Array(
                        [must] => Array(
                            [term] => Array(
                                [fk_product_category] => 1
                                [fk_product_group] => 1
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

When I remove one of the filters terms for example `fk_product_group` it works perfectly but when use both filters I get fatal error with code 400 Bad request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each filter must be in its own `term` filter

```
Array(
    [index] => galaxy
    [type] => galaxy
    [size] => 1000
    [from] => 0
    [body] => Array(
        [query] => Array(
            [filtered] => Array(
                [query] => Array(
                    [query_string] => Array(
                        [default_operator] => AND
                        [query] => vestel*
                    )
                )
                [filter] => Array(
                    [bool] => Array(
                        [must] => Array(
                            Array(
                               [term] => Array(
                                   [fk_product_category] => 1
                               )
                            ),
                            Array(
                               [term] => Array(
                                   [fk_product_group] => 1
                               )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```